# Google App Script - Create IF Statement to change and reset cell color when clicking on image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write an IF statement to reset the cell color when a user selects an image in error.

Default cell color is white.
If user clicks on image Then
cell c6 color changes to Green
Else
IF user clicks on image again Then
cell c6 color changes to White

[User Clicks image cell turns Green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLggw.jpg)

[User Clicks image again cell turns white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg8sz.jpg)

Script for changing cell color to Green when clicking on image:

```
function C2Green(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var colors = [
  ["#00ff40"] // this is green
  ];

  var cell = sheet.getRange("B6");
  cell.setBackgrounds(colors);
 
}
```

Script for resetting cell color when clicking on image again:

```
function C2Reset(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var colors = [
  ["#00FFFFFF"] // this is White
  ];

  var cell = sheet.getRange("B6");
  cell.setBackgrounds(colors);
 
}
```

I couldn't find an IF ELSE statement script based on Cell colors other than cell value.

Comment: try cell.setBackground("#00ff40"); or cell.setBackgrounds([["#00ff40"]]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `I am trying to write an IF statement to reset the cell color when a user selects an image in error.`, if an image is put over the cells on the Spreadsheet (This image is not put into a cell.) and a function of `C2Green` is assigned to the button, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

When you use this script, please assign the function `C2Green` to the button of the image. And, please click the button.

```js
function C2Green() {
  var cell = "B6"; // This is from your script.
  var colors = ["#00ff40", "#ffffff"]; // This is from your question and script.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // or ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(cell);
  var curentColor = range.getBackground();
  var color = colors.find(e => e != curentColor);
  range.setBackground(color);
}
```

- By this modification, when the background color of cell "B6" is `#00ff40`, the color is changed to `#ffffff`. And, when the background color of cell "B6" is `#ffffff`, the color is changed to `#00ff40`.
- This modified script is from your showing script. So, the cell "B6" is used. But, in your question, you say `Default cell color is white. If user clicks on image Then cell c6 color changes to Green Else IF user clicks on image again Then cell c6 color changes to White`. In this case, do you want to use the cell "C6"? If you want to use the cell "C6", please modify `var cell = "B6";` to `var cell = "C6";`.

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Hi Tanaike - This worked perfectly and I really appreciate your help.